# Video Java API for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there "videos java api" for GAE such as "Images Java API"?
All what I want is to upload file to Blobstore and retrieve it to play it (video stream from Blobstore). I tried to find an example to do that but I was not able to find any.

Please I need help me if you know any resource to do that.

I search stack-overflow but there is nothing.

Thank you,

Comment: its called [YouTube](http://youtube.com)!

Comment: Images API is intended for image manipulation - if you just need to store/retrieve videos, what's wrong with simple blob storage or google cloud storage?

Comment: @jarrod-roberson I did not get what you mean, however, I need to store the video to Blobstore then stream from there for research project to evaluate that.

Comment: @onon15 Thank you for your reply so how can I do that for a video file? I will upload it to the data storage but how will I stream the video file and play it?

Comment: For most uses, it will be enough to make the video file available on an HTTP server. You need to make sure both the video player you use and the format of the file you create support "progressive download". It's recommended to make sure the HTTP server supports "range" requests as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stream the video directly using a Servlet to serve it, example:

```
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey("YOUR BLOB KEY");
res.setContentType("video/mp4");
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
```

And then use a player like video.js: http://videojs.com/ to play it in flash or HTML 5